# How to grep for same pattern multiple times in a string using python?

Tags: python, regex

I am using python to pattern match a string multiple times in a string.
Problem:

```
string = 'The value = 1 The value = 2 The value = 3'
```

I want to grep only value but my output should be like:

```
['value = 1 value = 2 value = 3']
```

I am doing like this:

```
pattern = re.compile('[value = (\d+)]*')
values = pattern.search(string)
values.group(0)
```

Output:

```
''
```

i.e NULL (no match)

Please help me give the right regular expression to grep the required output.

Comment: There are no spaces between the `=` equals signs and the numbers in your input example, but your regular expression expects a space there. The output example is a single string in a list, did you mean to make that a list of 3 strings instead?

Comment: The string should be: string = 'The value = 1 The value = 2 The value = 3'. I am just keeping it. I am not sure whether list is involved or not...

Comment: Why are you having a `*` after your `bracket`?

Comment: It might match for multiple times...

Comment: As well as the answers you've got - a simple `string.replace('The ', '')` works in this case ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [' '.join(re.findall(r'value = \d+', string))]
['value = 1 value = 2 value = 3']
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a character class grouping. You should just use a normal grouping with `(`.

```
import re

string = 'The value = 1 The value = 2 The value = 3'

pattern = re.compile(r'(value = \d+)')
pattern.findall(string)
# OUT: ['value = 1', 'value = 2', 'value = 3']
" ".join(pattern.findall(string))
# OUT: 'value = 1 value = 2 value = 3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of square brackets (`[]`)  in the RE source is very odd. Those form character sets.

You should use something like:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'([^=]+)\s*=\s*(\d+)')
>>> pattern.findall(string)
[('The value ', '1'), (' The value ', '2'), (' The value ', '3')]
```

Note use of `findall()` to get all the matches, and grouping to get the value names too.

Comment: Thanks. But my output should be like one string: ['value = 1 value = 2 value = 3']